# url pass in the file for get a page

Tags: php, yii

I am creating a site in which I would like to go to another page via a custom menu. My menu code for the `views/layout/main.php` is:

```
  array('label'=>'create wireframe', 'url'=>array('wireframes/create'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

A user can go to the wireframe creation page, but it passes the url `index.php?r=user/wireframes/create`
but I only want `index.php?r=/wireframes/create`. How can it pass the url? Are there any additions that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try

```
'url'=>array('/wireframes/create').
```